# How can I replace special symbol line by special symbol new line

Tags: replace, special-characters, powershell-2.0

I have content stored in text file. In that, line 25 has below content

```
$userid = $null
```

Now I want to replace this line by

```
$userid = "Chandru"
```

I tried with below code but it didn't help me.

```
$content = Get-content c:\content.text
$oldline = "`$userid = `$null"
$newline = "`$userid = `"chandru`""
$newcontent = $content -replace ("$oldline","$newline")
```

This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`` "`$userid" `` escapes the `$` for PowerShell. You need to escape the `$` for the regular expression:

```psh
$oldline = '\$userid = \$null'
$newline = '$userid = "chandru"'
(Get-Content 'C:\content.text') -replace $oldline, $newline
```

You can use `[regex]::Escape()` if you want to escape all special characters in a string.